# How to display delay time of current agent in a delay block?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to display in a text object the current delay time of a delay block. In the value editor of the text object I have `sta1Delay.getDelayTime(agent)` which throws an error "agent cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: The value editor of the text object doesn't know what 'agent' means. That's because the agent is inside the delay block. If there is only 1 agent in the delay at a time, you could do: sta1Delay.getDelayTime(sta1Delay.get(0));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

In the "on enter" code box of your delay block, write `myText.setText("Delay time: "+delayTime);`

The keyword `delayTime` provides the duration for every new agent arriving.
[image]

Worth learning about those keywords, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling